# Rails ActiveRecord - inheriting from a base class with no table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What i'm looking to do is have a base class for some of my models that has some default activerecord behavior:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  def some_method
    #stuff
  end

  #etc..etc..
end

class ColorOption < Option
  #stuff...
end


class FabricOption < Option
  #stuff...
end
```

However, I want ColorOption and FabricOption to each be in their own tables.  I do NOT want to use STI or have a table for the base class "Option".  The only way I've gotten this to work is with some non-inheritance metaprogramming magic.  But I wondered if there was a way to tell AR that the base class does not need a table.  Its just there for extra behavior, and to put the other subclasses in their own table as usual.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like a case for a module that you include.

```
module Option
  def self.included(base)
    base.has_many :products
  end

  # other instance methods
end

class ColorOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Option
  set_table_name '???' # unless ColorOption / FabricOption have same table -> move to Option module

  #stuff...

end


class FabricOption < Option
  include Option
  set_table_name '???' # unless ColorOption / FabricOption have same table -> move to Option module

  #stuff...
end
```

More info: http://mediumexposure.com/multiple-table-inheritance-active-record/

Comment: yeah i tried the module, but the module cannot see the active record methods such as has_many :products.  It says the method is undefined.

Comment: fregas: make sure to include any class method calls, like `has_many` or validations inside the `self.included` method Stephan has in his example

Comment: ah the self.included refers back to the class that is including the module.  excellent, i'll try that!

Comment: sweet, that worked beautifully! yay ruby!  Much more elegant than the meta programming was doing...

Comment: Don't you have a typo in the last class definition, it should inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` not `Option`?

Answer (score 60):

What you want is an abstract class:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class ColorOption < Option
  ...
end

class FabricOption < Option
  ...
end
```

Comment: do i have to set the table name, or can AR just infer that?

Comment: No need to for the set_table_name, at least in Rails 3.2.

Comment: Combining this with Szymon Przybył's approach gave me the best results.  I added the following to the abstract class to automatically handle setting the table name for the inheriting classes:  def self.inherited(child)
    child.table_name = child.name.underscore.pluralize
  end

Comment: All I needed in rails 2.3 was the "abstract_class" part. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

I had similar problem, but I wanted also to change the way AR was setting table_name for my models, that for example MyProject model would have table name "MY_PROJECT".

I've achieved it by creating abstract AR class, as @FFrançois said, and with inherited method, where I'm changing table name, like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.table_name = subclass.name.underscore.upcase
  end
end

class MyProject < MyModel
end
```

Now MyProject.table_name gives MY_PROJECT :)